# How can I create stub functions?

Tags: rust

What's the best way to create a stub function in Rust? Something like:

```
fn my_method() -> bool {
  return new UnImplementedException() //wrong! But that's close to what I need
}
```

In C# the methods can return `UnImplementedException` which is convenient for creating stubs. Of course, in this particular case I could return true or false, but I want the solution that is applicable for any return type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `unimplemented!` macro ([doc link](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unimplemented!.html)).

```
fn my_method() -> bool {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head!